# PostgreSQL represent varchar column as boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, first_name from users;
```

I want to represent `first_name` column as a boolean. If user have `first_name` it will be true, if not it will be false. How can I do that in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test for `not null`:

```
SELECT id, first_name is not null  as has_first_name
from users;
```

If you want to consider an empty string (`''`) as "no first name as well, you can use:

```
SELECT id, nullif(first_name,'') is not null  as has_first_name
from users;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN first_name IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END
FROM users;
```

Comment: Nitpick: `'false'` is not a boolean, it's a character value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, that is 'true'. on the other hand, these values are implicitly converted to boolean if need.